# Collections.sort creates duplicate?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

**SOLVED:** The issue ultimately laid not in sorting but within my loops where I kept adding dealer cards but never removing them. This led to eventually feeding the dealer the same card twice (or more) leading to the apparent sorting issue.

So I have this class that I want to sort:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    private int suit;
    private int numeral;
    private int ID;

    public Card(int cardNo) {
        assert cardNo >= 0;
        assert cardNo < 52;
        this.suit = cardNo % 4;
        this.numeral = cardNo / 4;
        this.ID = cardNo;
    }

    public int compareTo(Card otherCard) {
        return Integer.compare(this.ID, otherCard.ID);
    }

public int getSuit() {
    return this.suit;
}

public int getNumeral() {
    return this.numeral;
}

    public String toString() {
        String[] suits = {"C", "D", "H", "S"};
        //String[] suits = {"♣", "♦", "♥", "♠"}; //clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades
        String[] numerals = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
        return numerals[this.getNumeral()] + suits[this.getSuit()];
    }
}
```

When I later create a List and sort it, the sorting seems broken. Here is an example: 2H 2S 3C 3D 3H 3S 4C sorts into 2H 2S 3C 3D 3H 3S 3S.

As you can see, it created a duplicate copy of 3S and got rid of 4C entirely. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here's the part where it breaks:

```
List<Card> sortedHand = new ArrayList<>(sevenCardHand);
System.out.println(sortedHand.get(0).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(1).toString() + " " +
        sortedHand.get(2).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(3).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(4).toString() +
        " " + sortedHand.get(5).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(6).toString() + "potato");
Collections.sort(sortedHand);
System.out.println(sortedHand.get(0).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(1).toString() + " " +
        sortedHand.get(2).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(3).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(4).toString() +
        " " + sortedHand.get(5).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(6).toString() + "tomato");
```

There is no omitted code so nothing else should be getting executed (as this is a single thread) but the second printout has the duplicate card while the first doesn't. The weirder part is that I can't replicate this in my unit tests.

EDIT2: Here is full code that breaks as described (that uses the Card class above)

```
@Test
void run() {
    SevenCardEvaluator sce = new SevenCardEvaluator();
    List<Card> deck = createDeck();
    Card playerCard2 = new Card(1);
    Card playerCard1 = new Card(0);
    deck.remove(playerCard2.getNumeral());
    deck.remove(playerCard1.getNumeral());
    for (int a = 0; a < 46; a++) {
        for (int b = a + 1; b < 47; b++) {
            for (int c = b + 1; c < 48; c++) {
                for (int d = c + 1; d < 49; d++) {
                    for (int e = d + 1; e < 50; e++) {
                        List<Card> playerHand = new ArrayList<>();
                        playerHand.add(playerCard1);
                        playerHand.add(playerCard2);
                        playerHand.add(deck.get(a));
                        playerHand.add(deck.get(b));
                        playerHand.add(deck.get(c));
                        playerHand.add(deck.get(d));
                        playerHand.add(deck.get(e));
                        int playerHandValue = sce.evaluate(playerHand);
                        List<Card> dealerDeck = new ArrayList<>(deck);
                        dealerDeck.remove(e);
                        dealerDeck.remove(d);
                        dealerDeck.remove(c);
                        dealerDeck.remove(b);
                        dealerDeck.remove(a);
                        List<Card> dealerHand = new ArrayList<>();
                        dealerHand.add(deck.get(a));
                        dealerHand.add(deck.get(b));
                        dealerHand.add(deck.get(c));
                        dealerHand.add(deck.get(d));
                        dealerHand.add(deck.get(e));
                        for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++) {
                            for (int j = i + 1; j < 45; j++) {
                                dealerHand.add(dealerDeck.get(i));
                                dealerHand.add(dealerDeck.get(j));
                                int dealerHandValue = sce.evaluate(dealerHand);
                                int playerWin = evaluateWin(playerHandValue, dealerHandValue);
                                addResult(playerWin, new int[]{deck.get(a).getNumeral(), deck.get(b).getNumeral(), deck.get(c).getNumeral(),
                                        deck.get(d).getNumeral(), deck.get(e).getNumeral()});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

List<Card> createDeck(){
    List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<52; i++){
        deck.add(new Card(i));
    }
    return deck;
}

int evaluateWin(int playerHandValue, int dealerHandValue){
    return 0; //dummy method
}

void addResult(int win, int[] cardIndices){
    //dummy method
}
```

And here is the SevenCardEvaluator class it uses:

```
public class SevenCardEvaluator {
    public SevenCardEvaluator(){}
    public int evaluate(List<Card> sevenCardHand){
        List<Card> sortedHand = new ArrayList<>(sevenCardHand);
        System.out.println(sortedHand.get(0).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(1).toString() + " " +
                sortedHand.get(2).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(3).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(4).toString() +
                " " + sortedHand.get(5).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(6).toString() + "potato");
        Collections.sort(sortedHand);
        System.out.println(sortedHand.get(0).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(1).toString() + " " +
                sortedHand.get(2).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(3).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(4).toString() +
                " " + sortedHand.get(5).toString() + " " + sortedHand.get(6).toString() + "tomato");
//dummy class
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals. ...`
You should carefully read the javadoc for `Comparable` interface
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://ideone.com/KrA4dE)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @NeplatnyUdaj Does this imply that I need to implement the equals method?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem here(because I don't see the data in the question), but when `compareTo` returns 0 for some objects and `equals` on those object returns false(it is your case since you didn't override it), it will cause problems when sorting.

Comment: Are you 100% positively sure that the duplication happens during sorting? Cause that would be extremely weird. It's probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: As the comment by user Michael shows, what you've pasted works just fine. You haven't posted how you sort and what you are sorting; presumably the problem lies there.

Comment: Implementing the equals method did not change anything sadly. @tobias_k I'm not 100% certain in that I can't repeat it in my unit tests but in the actual code when I print it right before sorting and right after sorting it prints as described in the question.

Comment: @rzwitserloot edited in the relevant part now

Comment: You did omit code; for example, the creation of the sevenCardHand variable. I suggest you write a fully self-contained test case (you're nearly there at this point), which we can just dump into ideone or glot.io and see the results.

Comment: @rzwitserloot fair enough, I more-so meant that there is no omitted code that should be executed during the snippet as there is definitely code before. I will try doing as you suggest.

Comment: @rzwitserloot added full code now, if you run it you will see that the sorted "tomato" printout creates a duplicate fairly often even though the unsorted "potato" printout is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the long post, but a well designed object model can go a long way. If you containerize the deck and hands, then you can use them interchangeably when dealing-out cards and inserting them.

Here are the classes that you can find below:

- `AbstractDeck.java`
- `Actions.java`
- `Card.java`
- `CardHolder.java`
- `Casino.java`
- `Container.java`
- `Deck.java`
- `Hand.java`
- `Player.java`
- `TexasHoldem.java`

### Casino

A driver program to shuffle a deck of card, deal cards to players, and sort their hands.

```
package casino;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Casino {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Player> players = Arrays.asList("Bob", "Jill", "Thomas").stream()
                .map(Player::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        TexasHoldem holdem = new TexasHoldem();

        holdem.dealCards(players, 2);
        holdem.sortHands(players);
        holdem.play(players);
        holdem.printInfo(players);
    }
}
```

### Ouput

```
# FLOP
Player [name=Bob, hand=Hand [cards=[5S, JS]]] => Hand [cards=[5S, 7D, JD, JS, QD]]
Player [name=Jill, hand=Hand [cards=[9H, AH]]] => Hand [cards=[7D, 9H, JD, QD, AH]]
Player [name=Thomas, hand=Hand [cards=[4C, 8S]]] => Hand [cards=[4C, 7D, 8S, JD, QD]]

# TURN
Player [name=Bob, hand=Hand [cards=[5S, JS]]] => Hand [cards=[5H, 5S, 7D, JD, JS, QD]]
Player [name=Jill, hand=Hand [cards=[9H, AH]]] => Hand [cards=[5H, 7D, 9H, JD, QD, AH]]
Player [name=Thomas, hand=Hand [cards=[4C, 8S]]] => Hand [cards=[4C, 5H, 7D, 8S, JD, QD]]

# RIVER
Player [name=Bob, hand=Hand [cards=[5S, JS]]] => Hand [cards=[5H, 5S, 6C, 7D, JD, JS, QD]]
Player [name=Jill, hand=Hand [cards=[9H, AH]]] => Hand [cards=[5H, 6C, 7D, 9H, JD, QD, AH]]
Player [name=Thomas, hand=Hand [cards=[4C, 8S]]] => Hand [cards=[4C, 5H, 6C, 7D, 8S, JD, QD]]

# INFO
Deck [cards=[8C, TS, 3C, AD, QH, 7C, QC, 8D, TH, 4H, 4S, 6H, 2S, 6S, KC, TC, 3H, 4D, KS, 8H, JC, 9D, KH, 5D, TD, 2C, QS, KD, AC, 7S, 7H, 3S, JH, 2D, 2H, 3D, 5C, AS, 9C, 6D, 9S]]
Hand [cards=[7D, JD, QD, 5H, 6C]]
Player [name=Bob, hand=Hand [cards=[5S, JS]]]
Player [name=Jill, hand=Hand [cards=[9H, AH]]]
Player [name=Thomas, hand=Hand [cards=[4C, 8S]]]
```

### TexasHoldem

```
package casino;

import java.util.List;

public class TexasHoldem {
    private Deck deck;
    private Hand communityHand;

    public TexasHoldem() {
        deck = new Deck();
        communityHand = new Hand();
        deck.shuffle();
    }

    void printInfo(List<Player> players) {
        System.out.println("# INFO");
        System.out.println(deck);
        System.out.println(communityHand);
        players.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    void play(List<Player> players) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            communityHand.insert(deck.draw());
            if (i == 2) {
                System.out.println("# FLOP");
                compareHands(players, communityHand);
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                System.out.println("# TURN");
                compareHands(players, communityHand);
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (i == 4) {
                System.out.println("# RIVER");
                compareHands(players, communityHand);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public Hand viewHand(Player player, Hand community) {
        Hand view = new Hand();
        for (Card card : player.getHand().getCards()) {
            view.insert(card);
        }
        for (Card card : community.getCards()) {
            view.insert(card);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void compareHands(List<Player> players, Hand community) {
        for (Player player : players) {
            Hand view = viewHand(player, community);
            view.sort();
            System.out.printf("%s => %s%n", player, view);
        }
    }

    public void dealCards(List<Player> players, int cardsPerPlayer) {
        for (int round = 0; round < cardsPerPlayer; round++) {
            for (Player player : players) {
                player.getHand().insert(deck.draw());
            }
        }
    }

    void sortHands(List<Player> players) {
        for (Player player : players) {
            player.getHand().sort();
        }
    }
}
```

### Deck

A standard deck of 52 cards by rank and suit.

```
package casino;

import java.util.*;

public class Deck extends AbstractDeck<Card> implements CardHolder {
    public Deck() {
        items = new Stack<Card>();
        for (int cardNo = 0; cardNo < 52; cardNo++) {
            items.add(new Card(cardNo));
        }
    }

    public List<Card> getCards() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setCards(Stack<Card> cards) {
        this.items = cards;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Deck [cards=%s]", items);
    }
}
```

### Player

A player who holds a hand of cards.

```
package casino;

public class Player {
    private String name;
    private Hand hand;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Hand getHand() {
        return hand;
    }

    public void setHand(Hand hand) {
        this.hand = hand;
    }

    public Player(String name, Hand hand) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hand = hand;
    }

    public Player(String name) {
        this(name, new Hand());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Player [name=%s, hand=%s]", name, hand);
    }
}
```

### Hand

Represents a hand of cards.

```
package casino;

import java.util.*;

public class Hand extends AbstractDeck<Card> implements CardHolder {
    public Hand() {
        items = new Stack<Card>();
    }

    public List<Card> getCards() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setCards(Stack<Card> cards) {
        this.items = cards;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Hand [cards=%s]", items);
    }
}
```

### Card

Represents a standard playing card with suit and rank.

```
package casino;

public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    public static final String[] SUIT = { "C", "D", "H", "S" };
    public static final String[] RANK = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };

    private int id;
    private int suit;
    private int numeral;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public int getNumeral() {
        return numeral;
    }

    public void setNumeral(int numeral) {
        this.numeral = numeral;
    }

    public Card(int cardNo) {
        assert cardNo >= 0;
        assert cardNo < 52;

        this.id = cardNo;
        this.suit = cardNo % 4;
        this.numeral = cardNo / 4;
    }

    public int compareTo(Card otherCard) {
        return Integer.compare(this.id, otherCard.id);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s%s", RANK[this.getNumeral()], SUIT[this.getSuit()]);
    }
}
```

### CardHolder

Used to treat a Deck and a Hand as Card holders since they extend AbstractDeck.

```
package casino;

public interface CardHolder extends Container<Card> {
    // Just used as a category for Collection utilities of need be.
}
```

### Container

An interface that simulates a generic stack of items e.g. cards.

```
package casino;

public interface Container<E> {
    E peek();
    E draw();
    boolean insert(E element);
    void insertAt(int index, E element);
    void shuffle();
    void sort();
}
```

### AbstractDeck

An abstract implementation of a Container that holds Comparable items. A Deck and a Hand are very similar in this sense.

```
package casino;

import java.util.Stack;

public class AbstractDeck<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Container<T> {
    protected Stack<T> items;

    @Override
    public T peek() {
        return items.peek();
    }

    @Override
    public T draw() {
        return items.pop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(T item) {
        return items.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertAt(int index, T item) {
        items.add(index, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void shuffle() {
        Actions.shuffle(items);
    }

    @Override
    public void sort() {
        Actions.sort(items);
    }
}
```

### Actions

A static utility class to operate on generic lists.

```
package casino;

import java.util.*;

public class Actions {
    private static final Random rnd = new Random();

    /** Fisher–Yates shuffle */
    public static <E> void shuffle(List<E> list) {
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            E tmp = list.get(index);
            list.set(index, list.get(i));
            list.set(i, tmp);
        }
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void sort(List<E> list) {
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! It seems that the sort does in fact work correctly in a vacuum but still causes issues in the full code I edited in above.

Comment: @bad_fetus My updated code addresses hands of cards. I even sort the hands in the driver (`Casino.java`).

Comment: @Mr._Poliwhirl I'll try implementing it and get back to you. One difference I noticed is that each player has a different card in your example whereas my players share 5 cards (as I'm implementing a version of texas hold'em). Do you think this could be causing issues with the sort?

Comment: So I guess cards need to be shareable or you need to create a view containing the Player's cards and the community cards. Then you can sort that view.

Comment: @bad_fetus OK, set up the game like Texas Hold'em. After the Flop, the Turn, and the River: each player's hand is sorted along with the community cards. You can then determine if they have a straight, flush, pair, etc...

Comment: Solved! The issue ultimately was not directly related to the changes you suggested; but as usual, cleaning the coed up helped massively. In my code where I'm trying to loop through every card deal combination instead of shuffilng and dealing; I kept adding cards to the dealer's hand while never removing the older ones. Hence we ended up with duplicate cards. Since I assumed he always had 7 cards rather than properly checking it, it ended up uncaught. Thanks a lot for the help!